# check user in ad groups within groups

Tags: c#

I want to check whether a user is within an AD groups using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.  in normal case, i can do it by using user.IsMemberOf(Group).  However, if the group belongs to another group(parent group), using user.IsMemberOf(Parent Group) will failed.  Is there any easy way to do it? or do i have to recursively drill down where there are subgroups within a group?

e.g. we have group IT, and within IT group, we have Application, Infrastructure, Service Desk.  I belong to Application group only, and if i do user.ismemberof(Application), i get true.  if i do user.ismemberof(IT), i get false.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups` method, you'll get that for free :

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> *This method searches all groups **recursively** and returns the groups in which the user is a member. The returned set may also include additional groups that system would consider the user a member of for authorization purposes.*

Answer (score 0):

You will have to perform the search recursively until there are no more groups to search through. There isn't a built-in way to walk the chain of A/D memberships.